# Определение статического свойства типа с плавающей точкой в классе

Tags: c++, c++03

Если определить в классе свойство типа `uint32_t`, например:

```
static const uint32_t VALUE = 100;
```

то все ок, проблема возникает при определении свойства `float` или `double`, например:

```
static const float VALUE = 100.0f;
```

Ошибка компилятора `'constexpr' needed for in-class initialization of static data member 'const float TestClass::VALUE' of non-integral type [-fpermissive]`

Как можно определить не целое статическое свойство не вынося определение за пределы класса? И почему свойства целого типа определяются без ошибки.

Интересует вариант до 11 стандарта.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `inline`, если не хотите последовать совету и объявить `constexpr`...

Comment: @Harry, используемый стандарт не позволяет использовать, обновил вопрос, указав стандарт

Comment: ОФТОП. А вам принципиально именно переменную иметь, если нет рассмотрите замену на функцию. И еще в плюсах нет свойств, не надо термины от других перетягивать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

До C++11 возможно только раздельное объявление-определение статических членов типа `float`. Константность здесь ничего не меняет.

В классе делается объявление

```
class MyClass
{
  ...
  static const float VALUE;
  ...
};
```

В одном из файлов реализации - определение

```
const float MyClass::VALUE = 100.0f;
```

Инициализатор допускается указывать только в определении.

---

Имейте также в виду, то даже для целочисленных типов ваше "определение" в классе на самом деле не является *определением*. Это по-прежнему только *объявление*, пусть даже и с инициализатором. Избежать дополнительного определения за пределами класса можно, но только если ваша константа используется исключительно в value-контекстах (напр. в *целочисленных константных выражениях*). Но как только вы начнете использовать такой статический член в ODR-контекстах (т.е. как только вашему `VALUE` понадобится физическое положение в памяти), вам точно так же придется предоставить определение такого статического члена за пределами класса.

Это правило распространяется и на C++11. Возможность действительно поместить *определение* статического члена внутрь определения класса, появилась только в C++17 с появлением inline-переменных.

Comment: cпасибо за ответ. Можете подробнее пояснить, что за ODR-контекст? В каком случае может понадобиться для VALUE физическое положение в памяти?

Comment: @cassius: Попросту говоря, это контексты, в которых требуется, чтобы переменная существовала в памяти. Например, взятие адреса переменной через `&`, привязка ссылки к переменной, присваивание нового значения переменной (если бы не было `const`) и т.д. Практически все использования переменной, кроме использования в константных выражениях, являются такими.

Answer (score -3):

До введения 11 стандарта нельзя было объявлять статическую константу не целого типа:

```
static const float VALUE = 100.0f;
```

Приходилось обходиться без `const`:

```
static float VALUE;
```

Кроме `float` нельзя также делать с любыми типами, которые не являются Integral Type (целочисленные), различные `std::string`, `double` и прочие не получится.

Начиная с 11 стандарта можно так:

```
static constexpr float VALUE = 100.0f;
```

Компилировать в 11 стандарте, это значит, что должен быть флаг -std=c++11.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что до 11 стандарта определить свойство не целого типа возможно только за пределами класса?

Comment: @cassius Да, и обязательно неконстантным. По крайней мере долгий гуглёж пару месяцев назад на эту тему ничего толкового мне не подсказал.

Comment: Что за ерунда про "приходилось обходиться без const"? Что за ерунда про "обязательно неконстантным"? Откуда вы это взяли??? Никаких ограничений на константность/неконстантность нет и никогда не было.